# Get an image type BYTEA from an API response using flask and display it on React APP

Tags: reactjs, json, postgresql, api, flask

I am struggling with a project that I'm trying to do, basically my API on Flask works fine. I'm using Postgresql for my database and it's just saving into one table called "imagenes". Every image has an ID, name, imageName and imageData which is a BYTEA type, this field saves the image that I upload through my API.

The data is beign save as it's supposed to, but my problem comes when I try to get all the data from my database, including the image. Here's my Python code so I can explain it better:

```
@app.route("/api/imagenes")
def getImagenes():

conn, cur = createConnection()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM imagen")

imagenes = cur.fetchall()

conn.close()
print(type(imagenes))
print(imagenes)

jsonImagenes = {}

if imagenes:

    jsonImagenes['id'] = imagenes[0][0]
    jsonImagenes['nombre'] = imagenes[0][1]
    jsonImagenes['nombreImagen'] = imagenes[0][2]
    
    imagenData = imagenes[0][3]
    imagenEncoded = base64.b64encode(imagenData).decode('utf-8')

    jsonImagenes['imagenData'] = imagenEncoded

return jsonify(jsonImagenes), 200
```

What I'm basically doing is getting all the images from my database and encoding the imagenData to base64, so when I send my JSON as a response it can be serializable. When I do the GET request it works fine and I get the JSON.

My problem comes when I try to start my React App an showing it using the API, I've tried decoding the image from base64 and casting it to a blob object so I can render it on my component, but the image is not showing. I know I can save the images into a folder, but I want my API working on this way because I want to use it for another projects. I hope that someone can help me with this problem since it's really difficult to me because I don't have too much experience with React. Thanks.

Flask Code:

```
@app.route("/api/imagenes")
def getImagenes():

conn, cur = createConnection()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM imagen")

imagenes = cur.fetchall()

conn.close()
print(type(imagenes))
print(imagenes)

jsonImagenes = {}

if imagenes:

    jsonImagenes['id'] = imagenes[0][0]
    jsonImagenes['nombre'] = imagenes[0][1]
    jsonImagenes['nombreImagen'] = imagenes[0][2]
    
    imagenData = imagenes[0][3]
    imagenEncoded = base64.b64encode(imagenData).decode('utf-8')

    jsonImagenes['imagenData'] = imagenEncoded

return jsonify(jsonImagenes), 200
```

React Code (App.js):

```
    import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [imagen, setImagen] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/imagenes')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const imagenData = atob(data.imagenData); // decodificar la imagenData de base64
   

 console.log(imagenData);
    const imagenType = data.nombreImagen.split('.').pop(); // obtener la extensión de la imagen
    const imagenBlob = new Blob([imagenData], { type: `image/${imagenType}` }); // crear un objeto Blob
    const imagenUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imagenBlob); // crear una URL para la imagen
    console.log(imagenUrl);

    setImagen(imagenUrl);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al obtener la imagen:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {imagen ? (
        <img src={imagen} alt="Imagen" />
      ) : (
        <p>Cargando...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```